# ARC file compilation issue

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

ProjectA is ARC, SubProject is manually reference counted i.e not ARC.

ProjectA has SubProject embedded within it and builds it as a target dependency. So I thought that would mean it didn't matter if the SubProject was ARC or not, as ProjectA is linking to the compiled unit.

However, in ProjectA I import a header from SubProject and that header contains enums that are not ARC compliant. i.e (ARC forbids Object-C objects in struct).

Am I missing something simple to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually use the structs directly in ProjectA?  Yes, including the header isn't going to work, but you could make the structs private to the implementation, or make them use CFTypeRefs instead of NSObject pointers

Comment: I see. Well if it definitely isn't going to work, and it isn't something obvious I've missed in the project setup and compilation. Then I'll work around it. Thanks

Comment: I converted SubProject to ARC to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the struct objects pointers be __unsafe_unretained and that will work.
The thing is, even if your sub project is MRR, the parent project likely has `#import`s of your sub project, so its headers must comply with ARC requirements.

If you really mean to have plain old C structs with `id`'s in them, then __unsafe_unretained shall be used.